# General integral of $y' = 2t\sqrt{1 - y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have doubts about the general integral of $y' = 2t\sqrt{1 - y^2}$.

This is my attempt of solution:

The equation $y' = 2t\sqrt{1 - y^2}$ is of the form $y' = a(t)b(y)$ so I try to solve it by separating variables. $a(t) = 2t$ is continuous for all real numbers and $b(y) = \sqrt{1 - y^2}$ is defined on interval $J = \left[{-1},1\right]$ and is continuous on $J$.

**Case $b(y)=0$**

$$b(y) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow y=\pm1,$$
then $y=\pm 1$ are solutions of $y' = 2t\sqrt{1 - y^2}$.

**Case $b(y) \neq 0$**

$$\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1 - y^2}} =2t \Longleftrightarrow \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1 - y^2}} = t^2 + c \Longleftrightarrow \arcsin{y} = t^2 + c \Longleftrightarrow y = \sin(t^2 + c)$$
and I have to consider only $(t^2 + c) \in \left[{- \frac{\pi}{2}}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right]$ because sine function is non-injective on $\mathbb{R}$.

Finally, the general integral of $y' = 2t\sqrt{1 - y^2}$ is
$$y = \sin(t^2 + c), (t^2 + c) \in \left[{- \frac{\pi}{2}}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right] \wedge y = \pm 1$$

My doubts are:

- Are the $y = \pm 1$ solutions contained in $y = \sin(t^2 + c), (t^2 + c) \in \left[{- \frac{\pi}{2}}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right]$?
- Is $(t^2 + c) \in \left[{- \frac{\pi}{2}}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right]$ necessary? If I try to substitute $y = \sin(t^2 + c)$ I get $2t\cos(t^2 +c) = 2t\cos(t^2 + c)$ and this is true for $(t^2 + c) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The solutions should rather be expressed as $(y_c)$ for $c$ in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, where $y_{-\pi/2}(t)=-1$ for every $t$, $y_{\pi/2}(t)=1$ for every $t$, and, for every $|c|<\pi/2$, $y_c$ is defined piecewisely by $y_c(t)=\sin(t^2+c)$ for every $|t|<\sqrt{\pi/2-c}$ and $y_c(t)=1$ for every $|t|\geqslant\sqrt{\pi/2-c}$. Thus every solution $y_c$ is defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$ and, naturally, $c=\arcsin y(0)$. Note finally that some other solutions exist, starting from $y(0)=-1$ (Cauchy-Lipschitz does not hold at this point), but these would be longer to describe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you solve an ODE by separating variables, the *first* thing to do is to locate constant solution. These solutions are likely to get lost since you need to divide out by a factor that cannot be zero. Indeed, your couple of constant solutions does not belong to the other family of solutions, since $\sin (t^2+c)$ will never be independent of $t$.

Your second question is more subtle, let's see. As you noticed, your solution $y(t)=\sin (t^2+c)$ is a solution no matter what $t$ is. This is correct. So why do you see the requirement $t^2+c \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$? Just ask yourself what arcsin is: it is the "inverse" of sin. 
Of course you know that the sine function is not globally invertible, and we *agree* to call arcsin the inverse function of the restriction $\sin \colon [-\pi/2,\pi/2] \to [-1,1]$. But we could take any other interval of injectivity as well. The point is that 
$$
\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}
$$
is defined as long as $-1<y<1$, but there is no reason why we should put any restriction of the codomain of the resulting antiderivative.

Comment: Let me just make sure I understand you correctly: the general integral of  that ODE is $y = \sin(t^2 + c)$ without any restriction because the restriction I took was not the only that I could take. If I consider all restrictions I get $\dots \cup \left[{-3\pi}/2,{-\pi}/2\right] \cup \left[{-\pi}/2,\pi /2\right] \cup \left[\pi / 2, {3\pi}/2 \right] \cup \dots = \mathbb{R}$, so there are not restriction to apply to the argument $t^2 + c$.

Comment: Another viewpoint is this: you are drawing the level sets of the map $F(t,y)=\arcsin y -t^2$, namely $\{(t,y) \mid F(t,y)=c \}$. You will see that any point of the curve $y=\sin (t^2+k)$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$ belongs to some level set, and viceversa. The restriction on $t$ comes in because you try to "solve" the equation $F(t,y)=c$ with respect to $y$.